# bandwidth control during youtube upload

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, bandwidth, youtube, broadband

I am having a slow internet connection and I am looking for some solution so that I can divide the 1/5th of available bandwidth to me for youtube uploads while at the same time working with other things being connected to internet and rest of 4/5th of my bandwidth should be available to me to work.Is there a solution for the same?

I want a solution for Windows 7 and Ubuntu both

**UPDATE**
The router I have is ib-WRA 150 N 
http://www.flipkart.com/iball-150m-wireless-n-adsl2-router/p/itmd375x5yfzbsgb

I am not sure if it is possible in this router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to do this on the router with QoS. There are several open source firmwares that do this very well (see [Tomato](http://tomatousb.org/tut:using-tomato-s-qos-system) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service)).

It doesn't look like your [router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) supports those firmwares but that it does provide some level of QoS (see section 4.7.2 of the [manual](http://www.iballbaton.com/Download/70/iB-WRA150N%20User%20Guide.pdf)). Do some searching on configuring QoS for youtube and see if you can apply those rules with in your router settings.

Comment: I have following router http://www.flipkart.com/iball-150m-wireless-n-adsl2-router/p/itmd375x5yfzbsgb I am not sure if it is possible to do what you are saying with this router

Comment: Updated answer with some more info based on you router.